# omniauth with rails: get facebook user's information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, omniauth

in the callback of the authentication process I do:
`auth_hash = request.env['omniauth.auth']`

and then, I'm extracting the user id, but is it possible in the same time getting the user's name and email address?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to first get the raw data from request.env["omniauth.auth"]

```
  data = request.env["omniauth.auth"].extra.raw_info 
  username = data.first_name 
  email  = data.email
```

Comment: I have the same issue but missing the username field. It's not in the raw_info hash. how do I get it?

Answer (score 1):

yesss

u can get it by doing

```
     auth_hash[:info][:name] for name and auth_hash[:info][:email] for email
```