# Saving user location, bio, website upon signup through Facebook - Omniauth Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook-graph-api, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

Within my rails app, when someone signs up with Facebook, I'm trying to grab their email, name, image, location, bio, website.

I'm using [Omniauth Facebook](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook) Here is the [guide I followed](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview).

The signup works smoothly, I get no errors in the browser or in my logs, but the location, bio, and website all come back as nill. **What could be causing this? How can I fix this?**

**Am I allowed to call on user_location, user_about_me, user_website?**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2?locale=en_GB#reference

**Gem file**:

```
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
```

**User.rb**

```
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
    user.email = auth.info.email
    user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    user.name = auth.info.name  
    user.image = auth.info.image 
    user.location = auth.info.user_location 
    user.about = auth.info.user_about_me 
    user.website = auth.info.user_website 
  end
end
```

**Devise.rb initializer**

```
  config.omniauth :facebook, "APP_ID", "APP_SECRET",
          scope: 'email, user_location, user_about_me, user_website',
                  strategy_class: OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It looks like the "about me" and "website" isn't included in public profile and the locale has additional requirements, are you satisfying those? - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2?locale=en_GB#reference

Comment: Hey Ken! You're right, I have no clue how to satisfy the additional requirements. Is there some token or variable I have to store? Do I need to call on something like .extra.raw_info ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207211/omniauth-with-rails-get-facebook-users-information

Comment: I'm afraid not, sorry :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Facebook API documentation is rather confusing.

The problem is not with the rails code or the omniauth gem.

By default, Facebook only approves your application for grabbing a user's name, email, image, and a few other attributes.

To be able to grab any user's location, bio, or website, you need to individually apply for permission for each of these.